# Calculated date column to take into account working days

Tags: calculated-column

In my SharePoint list I have a default due date of

```
=Today+10
```

How can I get this default date to be 10 working days from today?

I'm not too worried about taking into account public holidays etc, taking into account Saturday and Sunday would be sufficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume that the item is created on a working day then adding 10 working days is easy as it's two weeks. So the following should work

```
=Today+14
```

If it's not a full number of working weeks then you need to use `IF` on `Weekday(Today)` see [Working Days, Weekdays and Holidays in SharePoint Calculated Columns](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/working-days-weekdays-holidays-sharepoint-calculated-columns/)

Comment: That's so obvious I feel a bit daft I didn't think of that myself, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can fix that problem with an `if`

```
=if(weekday(Today + 10,2)=6,Today + 10 + 2,if(weekday(Today + 10,2)=7,Today + 10 +1,Today + 10)
```